# How to use multiple database in wordpress?

Tags: database

I  want to fetch some post from another wordpress site which is hosted in the same server. How can I fetch those post?

Is multiple database connection is possible in wordpress?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible but you must manually create a new instance of the `wpdb` class with right settings for your other database.

Quote from the [wpdb Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb):

> The $wpdb object can talk to any number of tables, but only one
>   database: the WordPress database. In the rare case you need to connect
>   to another database, you will have to instantiate your own object from
>   the wpdb class with the appropriate connection details. For extremely
>   complicated setups with many databases, consider using hyperdb
>   instead.

Comment: Thanks Hamid for your reply. I have create a new instance of global wpdb class and its work fine.

Comment: It's not Hamid, my name is Hamed. And you are welcome. You might as well check this answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HyperDB: https://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/
It allows multiple databases, also read/write replicas or master / slave.

Answer (score 0):

1) Download class db at link: https://codeshack.io/super-fast-php-mysql-database-class/
 - rename class db = db_custom

2) .../themes/theme-name/functions.php

$dbhost = 'db_ip'; // 127.0.0.1
$dbuser = 'db_user'; // input database username
$dbpass = 'db_user_password'; // input your database password
$dbname = 'db_user_name'; // input your datatabase name

$db_watch = new db_custom($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 0,2";
$results = $db_watch->query($sql)->fetchAll();
print_r($results);

I have tested my website WordPress it's working well